# Combinations of a STEP paper question

Tags: combinatorics

A STEP paper consists of 8 Pure questions, 4 Statistics questions and 5 Mechanics questions. In how many ways can a candidate choose 5 questions, if they do at least one of each type?

The answer says it should be $4040$, however my thought process was that there were three options:

2P 1S 1M, 1P 2S 1M, 1P 1S 2M;

and I would calculate the answer as follows:

${8}\choose{2}$$\times 4 \times 5$ $+$ $8 \times$${4}\choose{2}$$\times 5$ $+$ $8\times 4 \times$${5}\choose{2}$$=1120$.

What other options am I overlooking?

Comment: Never mind - I can see a glaring error now I can see it on the big screen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible combinations for (P, S, M) P being Pure, S being Statistics and M being Mechanics.

(2,2,1),(2,1,2)(1,2,2)(1,1,3)(1,3,1)(3,1,1)

Thus the number of ways are

${8\choose2}{4\choose2}{5\choose1}+{8\choose2}{4\choose1}{5\choose2}+{8\choose1}{4\choose2}{5\choose2}+{8\choose1}{4\choose1}{5\choose3}+{8\choose1}{4\choose3}{5\choose1}+{8\choose3}{4\choose1}{5\choose1}=4040$